# roslaunch prevents node from creating/writing to file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For our current project, we created a launch file that initializes several nodes, one of which is supposed to create a log file, open it, write a header line at the beginning of the file, and then close the file.

When we run the nodes individually from terminal, this function works fine, but when the project is run from a launch file, the log file is never created. Do nodes run from a launch file not have permission to create new log files?

Function to create log file:

```
char Beacon::createLogFile(char *logDataFileName)
```

{

```
int status;
status = mkdir("Log", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);

if (status == -1)
{
        // error; it might be that the directory already exists
        if (errno == EEXIST)
        {
            // no problem
        }
        else if (errno == EACCES)
        {
            printf("Permission\n");
                return 1;
        }
}
else
{
        // Directory successfully created

}

FILE* logData_f_stream;
logData_f_stream = fopen(logDataFileName, "w");

fprintf(logData_f_stream, "NodeID Latitude Longitude Time OWTT\n");
fclose(logData_f_stream);


return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38045/roslaunch-prevents-node-from-creating/writing-to-file/) by [UW NDCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/2777/uw-ndcl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look for your log file in your `~/.ros` directory when starting nodes from launch files.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-07-05**:
or alternatively, set absolute path for the file name, so you know exactly where to look.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-07-06**:
Be careful with absolute paths though because this will make your code less portable if/when other people start using your work or if/when you try to use your own code on a different computer with a different directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just as some additional information to the answer of Thomas D: the 'current working directory' of the nodes launched via roslaunch gets set to the `$HOME/.ros` directory by default. See 'Is there a way for roslaunch to run nodes in the current directory?' on [ros-users](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/) for a discussion.

The `cwd` attribute of the `node` tag in a launch file can be used to change this behaviour:

> cwd="ROS_HOME|node"(optional)

> If 'node', the working directory of the node will be set to the same directory as the node's executable. In C Turtle, the default is 'ROS_HOME'. In Box Turtle (ROS 1.0.x), the default is 'ros-root'. The use of 'ros-root' is deprecated in C Turtle.

See the [roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes) wiki page and also [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2363) ticket.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2